# jquery change html and use slideDown in the new HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change a piece of my html using the .html, but i want add some slideDown effect, so i'm trying like this:

```
$('.section').slideDown(500, function () {
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

But is not working, the html change but the animate is not happening.

What i am doing wrong?

Example:

```
<p class="click">Click me</p>

<div class="section">
    <p> ONE </p>
    <p> ONE </p>
    <p> ONE </p>
    <p> ONE </p>
    <p> ONE </p>
</div>


$('.click').on('click', function() {
    $('.section').slideDown(500, function () {
        $(this).html('two');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fa7Ld2j1/

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please? Also a jsFiddle example would be helpful.

Comment: The paragraphs in your section are already visible, so slideDown won't do anything.  Also, your .html() line will replace all the paragraphs within your div, is that what you want, or do you want all the paragraphs within the div to have their HTML changes from one to two?

Comment: yes, i want change all the html for a new one using a slideDown effect

Comment: OK, so then I'm just not clear on the effect you're after now. After clicking the "click me", should the contents slide up, change, then slide down, or should the new content of each paragraph appear to slide down over the old content?

Comment: YEES!!! the old content should slide up, and the new one slide down

Comment: So like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fa7Ld2j1/1/?

Comment: OK, I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: In your fiddle you didn't choose any jquery library . so first select the resource then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sequence:

```
$('.click').on('click', function () {
    $('.section').slideUp(4500, function () {
        $(this).find('p').html('two');
        $('.section').slideDown(500)
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fa7Ld2j1/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The function to load the html is called as the `success` function, i.e. after the animation completes.

You can probably try this:

```
$('.section').hide(); // hide the section
$('.section').html(html); // populate..
$('.section').slideDown(500); // Slide Down
```

Hope it helps.. :)

Edit: Arguments for the slideDown can be checked 
[here](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/#slideDown1) ...

Comment: You can increase time argument in the `slideDown` call. Check the link to the function API in the answer edit..

Answer (score -1):

The slideDown is used to show something hidden,try the slideUp and then add alert(...) in the callback function.u will see the effect.
hope it helps